# Setting an undefined key of an object to undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined

If I open my JavaScript console (F12 on Chrome) and define a variable `var x = {};` and then type `x` in the console it shows me an empty object like this: `{}`. So far so good.

If try to see `x.a` the console will give me `undefined`, and if I explicitly test `x.a === undefined` it gives `true`. So far so good.

Everything is telling me that the value of `x.a` is `undefined`.

So, since its value is undefined, I now execute a command that I was expecting to do **absolutely nothing:** `x.a = undefined;`. I thought this shouldn't change anything.

But now if I put `x` in the console, it shows `{a: undefined}` instead of `{}`. This is an evidence that something changed...

**1. What is happening here?**

**2. Is there any situation in which this would make a difference?**

**3. If yes, how can I make that object go back to its initial state?**

Note: of course, for question 3, re-assigning to a new `{}` is obviously not an option, since it would no longer `===` to the previous value.

Comment: **You got good answers down below, but I'm going to address that last note you added**: remember that object literals will never be equal to other object literals, except the ones that reference that same literal object. For example, doing `{} === {}` returns `false`, but doing  ```var a = b = {}; a === b;``` turns out to be `true`

Comment: @GMaiolo, thanks, I know, that's exactly why I said that re-assigning to a new {} is not an option.

Comment: I was adding the clarification to your note just in case someone that does not know that happens to read this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What is happening here?

At first you are accessing a **non-existing** property. That will always return `undefined` as defined in the language specification.

But a property can also exist and have the value `undefined`, which is what you are getting when doing

```
x.a = undefined;
```

This creates the property `a` on `x` and assigns the value `undefined` to it.

> 2. Is there any situation in which this would make a difference?

Testing the existence of the property would result in `false` in the first case and `true` in the second case.

```js
var x = {};
console.log('a exists', 'a' in x);

x.a = undefined;
console.log('a exists', 'a' in x);
```

The value of the property is irrelevant when testing for existence.

Similarly, getting all properties of an object would yield different results:

```js
var x = {};
console.log(Object.keys(x));

x.a = undefined;
console.log(Object.keys(x));
```

> 3. If yes, how can I make that object go back to its initial state?

You can delete properties using the `delete` operator:

```
delete x.a;
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript treats the setting of a property to **any** value as a meaningful thing. The `in` operator illustrates:

```
var x = {};
console.log("a" in x); // false
x.a = undefined;
console.log("a" in x); // true
```

The `in` operator is the solid way to test whether a particular key is present in an object regardless of value. There's also the `Object.hasOwnProperty()` function if it matters that the property be *directly* present on the object.

If you want to get rid of a property completely, you can use `delete`:

```
delete x.a;
console.log("a" in x); // false
```

The `undefined` "value" (is it really a value?) is essentially a wart on the design of JavaScript; it makes it such that the language has effectively two `null` values. I understand why it's there, but that doesn't make the situation any easier to deal with.

Comment: *"is it really a value?"* According to the language specification yes :)

Comment: @FelixKling well sure, but there's something odd about it nevertheless!

Comment: I absolutely agree with that :D I teach a JavaScript class where I work and I always say to not *create* `undefined` values in your own code (it's fine to use it for comparison) and only use `null` to express the "absence of a value". Only let the language use `undefined` to tell you something is missing. (you know all that already, but hopefully this is useful for other visitors).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the key like so:

`delete x.a;`